# How to use django-urls-sugar and ssl middleware together?

Tags: django, ssl

I have been using django for a few months and the ssl middleware to redirect to https from http in my urls. In order to use more complex urls, I decided to use django-urls-sugar and it works fine but I do not know how to pass more parameters than the url parameters, the view and the name identifying the view.

`url_sugar([Constant('ardataset'),`
`Variable('band_id', '\d+'),`
`Variable('version', '\d+'),`
`], LoggedInViewArDataset.as_view(), name='ar-dataset-view-get'),`

This works but as soon as I want to use {'SSL': True} or passing the value as a keyword argument, it does not work.

Comment: Never heard of url-sugar before, but I'd be cautious with it. Aside from "variable disambiguation" it doesn't do anything that you can't do with the regex itself, and the variable disambiguation uses colons (:) which aren't exactly kosher in the URL path. It'll probably work 99.9% of the time, but I can see plenty of instances where it could potentially break severely.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with the new version of `django-urls-sugar`, released today.

BTW, replying to what @chris-pratt said, it's true that it doesn't do anything that you can't do by yourself, but this is what any "sugar" library is intended to do, right? `django-templatetags-sugar` for template tags, `django-urls-sugar` for urls. You can perfectly live without them, they are just intended to make you life easier in some (rare?) cases.